# How to stop the expert working in mql4/mql5 language

Tags: mql4, mql5

Is there an easier way to have 2 experts installed on mt4/mt5 and 1 expert stop the other expert from running?

Comment: this way i don't want to close all ea's. https://www.mql5.com/en/code/39068

Comment: Set a globalvariable in one EA and make the other check for it.

Comment: There are so many solutions such as kerne32.dll etc. on the internet. Global variables had never occurred to me. Thanks to you, I solved my problem. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [GlobalVariables](https://book.mql4.com/variables/globals). Use the expert that will stop the other to set a GlobalVariable. Make the other EA check for the presence of the global variable and if found, it can be set to pause operations.